# JQUERY: Simple get Offsets of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, position, offset

i would like get the offsets of a div,but when i try to access to that div says me [Object object]... or undefined or 0.0;because i think that my method is wrong :-(

This is the code of the page:

http://pastebin.org/208836

And i have already tried with this code:

```
var p = $(".product_72ivnj");
var offset = p.offset();
var final =( "left: " + offset.left + ", top: " + offset.top );
alert(final);
```

Or this:

```
var p = $("#product_72ivnj");
var offset = p.offset();
var final =( "left: " + offset.left + ", top: " + offset.top );
alert(final);
```

But won't work :-(

Anyone can help me please?

Thanks in advance.

Kind regards.

Luca.

Comment: Your pastebin link does not work for me.

Comment: your code should work fine. http://jsbin.com/opohe4

Comment: Perhaps you made a mistake with your html.  Could you post more code please?  Your link also did not work for me.

Comment: Link fixed,thanks to all.. Now is the FULL code of page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to wait for the page to be loaded ?

```
$(document).ready(function(){...});
```

Not so sure about the syntax you should check it on jQuery documentation.

Comment: I have forgotten to add this code :-(  .. Thanks you and to all for support :-)